# PHP Simple HTML Dom not Working fine

Tags: php, html, arrays, dom, simple-html-dom

Here is my code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$page = file_get_html($_REQUEST['url']);
$page = $page->find('table[class=cf-table-style sorted]',0)->find('tbody',0);
echo ($page);
```

`echo $page` is suppose to print HTML but it prints a `Array`, which means `find('tbody',0)` is returning array. It shouldn't do like that i think

Where is error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `find` function returns array no matter what. Just echo the first element:
`echo($page[0]);`

Comment: i don't think so, find('tbody') will return Array but find('tbody',0) will return first element of array

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract it using foreach and then echo e.g

```
foreach($page as pg){
echo pg;
}
```

try this it may work.

Comment: you're missing `$` sign in front of your vars.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = $page->find('table[class=cf-table-style sorted]',0)->find('tbody',0)->innertext;
```

**EDIT 1**

`innertext` returns HTML! Try it in this way:

```
$chunk = $page->find('table[class=cf-table-style sorted] tbody',0)->innertext;

echo $chunk;
```

Comment: i need html, not inner or plain text

Comment: @wasim innertext returns HTML! I edited my answer with another snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$page = $page->find('table[class=cf-table-style sorted]',0)->find('tbody',0)->plaintext;
print_r($page);
```

Comment: i need to move forward, i don't need plaintext, i need html

Comment: Use innertext instead of plaintext. Refer [Doc](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_access_special)